# Rotating a line every second using repaint and a timer

Tags: java, swing, timer, paint, repaint

So I'm trying to rotate a line every second using a Timer and a paint method. However, I'm not quite sure whats going on. Here are some of the relevant methods:

```
public static ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Clock cl = new Clock();
        seconds++;
        cl.repaint();
    }
};


public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    for(int c = 0; c<10; c++){
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.drawOval(90-c/2,90-c/2,500+c,500+c); //thick outlined circle
    }
    g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fillOval(90,90,501,501);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(seconds*6));
    g2.drawLine(340,340,340,90);    

}
```

The line remains stationary. However if I add

```
System.out.println("tick");
```

to my actionPerformed method, the command line spits out "tick" 3 times a second. Any ideas as to why these things are happening?

Some context:

```
public static int seconds = 0;
public static int minutes = 0;
public static int hours = 0;
public static Clock cl = new Clock();
private ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("tick");
        seconds++;
        cl.repaint();
    }
};
public static Timer timer = new Timer(1000,taskPerformer);

public static void main(String[] args){
    Clock cl = new Clock();
    init();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
public static void init(){
    timer.start();
}
public Clock() {
    super("Clock");
    timer.addActionListener(taskPerformer);

}
```

Comment: What is happening inside Clock.repaint()?

Comment: @smerlung I don't have a repaint method, it's supposed to call the paint method if i'm not mistaken

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new clock at every tick:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Clock cl = new Clock();
    ...
```

Instead you should use an existing instance.

```
// A field in the class:
Clock cl = new Clock();
...

// removed static so that it can access cl
private ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        seconds++;
        cl.repaint();
    }
};
```

You could also make the clock a field in the action listener, if you do not need to access it elsewhere.

Also note that you generally should not be overriding `paint()`, but should override `paintComponent()` instead. More about custom painting in swing [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

**Edit:**
Now that there's more code available, it's possible to say that if you make the clock and action listener static it should work. *However*, you need to start the timer after the relevant components are ready:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // Removed spurious clock here
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
            // Start the timer once the components are ready
            init();
        }
    });
}
```

The above mentioned point about *not* creating a clock in the action listener still stands.

Comment: Thanks. I made the 

    public static Clock cl = new Clock();

outside of the methods and I'm getting an ExceptionInInitializationError caused by a NullPointerException

Comment: my mistake-- forgot to make taskPerformer private. But when I try to create a timer with `public static Timer timer = new Timer(1000,taskPerformer);`, it says it cannot be referenced from a static context. Edited OP with more code

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to make the Timer static? I made both the action listener and clock instance variables because that's usually the right thing to do. If you insist on making everything static you'll need to ensure that they're initialized in the correct order.

Comment: I can't call timer.start(); in init() because of the static context. is there a better place to call it?

Comment: @CortneyReagle see edit. I'd recommend not making everything `static` though, as that approach does not scale.

Comment: +1, Read the Swing tutorial. All the examples in the tutorial show you a better way to design your program so you don't use static variables and methods. The tutorial will teach you the Swing basics.